# perl, append a character to i-th capturing group

Tags: regex, perl

I have this one liner:

```
perl -pe 's|.*?((\d{1,3}\.){3})xxx.*|\1|'
```

I feed this command with some input, like `192.168.1.xxx`, and it works. Now, I want to append a 0 to the output sequence, but of course if I just append the 0 right after the `\1` it will be parsed as the tenth capturing group. How can I concatenate then it to the `\1` directive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You [should use `$1` instead of `\1` in substitutions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5C1-Instead-of-%241).  Then you can use braces to write it unambiguously like this:

```
perl -pe 's|.*?((\d{1,3}\.){3})xxx.*|${1}0|'
```